# How to do / to /index redirection for an application when I am using haproxy ingress rules

Tags: haproxy, kubernetes, ingress

I am using HAProxy Ingress Controller and have rules set for `/index` and `/app`.

I want any traffic on `/` to be redirected to `/index`. How can I achieve this?

I Have 4 deployments via haproxy, default-backend (on `/` gives 404 and `/healthz` gives 200), index and app.

### index-ingress.yaml -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: index-haproxy
  namespace: haproxy
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "haproxy"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "index"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
       - path: /index
         backend:
          serviceName: index-backened
          servicePort: 443
```

### app-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-haproxy
  namespace: haproxy
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "haproxy"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:       
        - path: /app/
          backend:
           serviceName: application
           servicePort: 443
```

Comment: Please share your `ingress.yaml`

Comment: added ingress.yaml in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try with [HAProxy Ingress rewrite](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrite).

> ### Annotations
>
> The following annotations are implemented:
>
> ...
>
> - `ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root`: Defines the URL to be redirected when requests are done to the root context  `/`.

Or using a [Rewrite Target](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress#rewrite-target).

Comment: I have used this annotation as  ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /index but still getting 404 default backend error when I hit http://example.com/

Comment: you added it to index-ingress.yaml?

Comment: yes I have added that to index-ingress.yaml

Comment: try by adding second `path: /`that will point to the same backend